# Combine path + list of files to list of absolute files

Tags: bash, shell, path

If I have this data in my shell script:

```
DIR=/opt/app/classes
JARS=a.jar:b.jar:c.jar
```

How can I combine this to the string

```
/opt/app/classes/a.jar:/opt/app/classes/b.jar:/opt/app/classes/c.jar
```

in Shell/Bash scripting?

Comment: Do you really want to exclude the c.jar ?

Answer (score 11):

Here's a very short one:

```
$ echo "$DIR/${JARS//:/:$DIR/}"
/opt/app/classes/a.jar:/opt/app/classes/b.jar:/opt/app/classes/c.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind an extra semicolon at the end:

```
[~]> for a in `echo $JARS | tr ":" "\n"`;do echo -n $DIR/$a:;done&&echo      
    /opt/app/classes/a.jar:/opt/app/classes/b.jar:/opt/app/classes/c.jar:
```

Answer (score 0):

Use translate and iterate through the results. Then trim the result ':' character at the beginning of the string.

```
#! /bin/bash

DIR=/opt/app/classes
JARS=a.jar:b.jar:c.jar

for i in $(echo $JARS | tr ":" "\n")
do
    result=$result:$DIR/$i
done
echo ${result#:} // Remove the starting :
```

Result:

```
/opt/app/classes/a.jar:/opt/app/classes/b.jar:/opt/app/classes/c.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure Bash, no external utilities:

```
saveIFS=$IFS
IFS=:
jararr=($JARS)
echo "${jararr[*]/#/$DIR/}"
IFS=saveIFS
```

**Original Answer (before question was revised):**

```
IFS=: read -ra jararr <<<"$JARS"
newarr=(${jararr[@]/#/$DIR/})
echo "${newarr[0]}:${newarr[1]}"
```

Comment: Doesn't that only echo the first two entries?  `(IFS=:; echo "${jararr[*]/#/$DIR/}")`

Comment: @ephemient: It did what the original question asked for. It's been revised so I'll revise my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Pure Optimized Bash 1-liner

```
IFS=:; set -- $JARS; for jar; do path+=$DIR/${jar}:; done; echo "$path"
```

#### Output

```
/opt/app/classes/a.jar:/opt/app/classes/b.jar:/opt/app/classes/c.jar:
```